# How to modify the link for Help under ? in standard sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint

How to modify the link for Help that shows under question mark "?" at the top menu in a standard sharepoint page programatically. By default that opens a page https://sitecollection/_layouts/15/help.aspx?Lcid=1033&Key=HelpHome&ShowNav=true

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: I don't think we'll be able to modify this link, which seems to have been designed by SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to customize the SharePoint Help link using SharePoint out of the box options.

Microsoft does not support such customizations in SharePoint sites.

Check this threads for more information:

1. [Hiding Office 365 Ribbon in SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/297914/hiding-office-365-ribbon-in-sharepoint/297915#297915)
2. [How can I include the same JS and CSS files on multiple SharePoint Modern Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/how-can-i-include-the-same-js-and-css-files-on-multiple-sharepoint-modern-page/277353#277353)